# Azure Face API, python SDK attribute url

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm using the Python SDK snippet provided by [Azure docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiinpythontutorial)

```
BASE_URL ="https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)
```

I want to return face attributes, The docs [referenced here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) suggest that adding

```
/detect[&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender]
```

To the Base URl will return age and gender attributes. It's throwing me an error, am I missing something?

This is my first time using Azure Face API.

Comment: New generation of FaceSDK has been released yesterday (literally): https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/ and sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-python-sdk-samples/blob/master/samples/vision/face_samples.py. The SDK you mentionned will be tagged soon as deprecated (I work at MS in the SDK team)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use the follow code to get the returnFaceAttributes

```
faces = CF.face.detect(img_url,attributes='age,gender')
```

**Whole demo code**

```
import cognitive_face as CF
KEY = 'xxxxx'  # Replace with a valid subscription key (keeping the quotes in place).
CF.Key.set(KEY)
BASE_URL = 'https://{location}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0'  # Replace with your regional Base URL
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)
#You can use this example JPG or replace the URL below with your own URL to a JPEG image.
img_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Windows/master/Data/detection1.jpg'
faces = CF.face.detect(img_url,attributes='age,gender')
```

**Test Result:**

[image]